# Django DRF how to limit items created at a time in serializer

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm setting POST API endpoint(in Django Rest Framework) to add offers for auction. Hovewer there are two constraints which Im not sure how to handle:

1) Bidder can have maximum of three offers per single auction

2) Offers from same bidder for same auction can't be the same(duplicated)

The bidder can apply multi offers in one request, but I dont know how to validate that he doesn't send more than 3 offers, and how to check if he sends 2 new offers while he posted 2 offers before(so he exceeded the limit).

The same applies for offers duplication, I tried to check for that in serializers "validate" method checking for already sent offers, but nothing is found when processing new offers. It looks like they are being commited to DB together, aren't they?

Offer Viewset - Here I used code found on Stackoverflow for allowing list of items being created in single POST request

```py
class OfferViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.CreateModelMixin):

    serializer_class = OfferSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsValidBidder,)

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
            kwargs['many'] = True
        return super(OfferViewSet, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here are parts of OfferSerializer

```py
def validate(self, attrs):
    ...
    already_placed_offers_qs = Offer.objects.filter(
        bidder=attrs['bidder'],
        auction=attrs['auction']
    )

    if already_placed_offers_qs.count() >= 3:
        raise LimitExceededError()

    # check for already existing same object
    if already_placed_offers_qs.filter(...).exists():
        raise DuplicationError()

    return attrs
```

Unfortunatelly this validation doesn't work if I submit multi offers in one request.

I expect that it will check if single bidder hasn't exceeded limit of 3 offers per auction no matter if he sent single request with 4 offers, or several requests with one offer.
It also should check for duplicates, e.g. if multi offers are sent in one request it should prevent to add duplicates(like I tried in validate method)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Unique Together

To cover (2) is relatively simple, and can be done by making the necessary fields (`user`, `auction`, `price`, probably?) unique together either [at at the model level](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) or [at the serializer level](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator).

#### List Validation

(1) is probably best handled by writing your own [list serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer) and put the validation in there.  Something like this:

```
class OfferListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        already_placed_offers_qs = Offer.objects.filter(
            bidder=attrs['bidder'],
            auction=attrs['auction']
        )
        if already_placed_offers_qs.count() + len(attrs) > 3:
            raise LimitExceededError()

        return attrs

    ...

class OfferSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...
    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = OfferListSerializer
        ...
```

**NOTE**: I used your `LimitExceededError`, but in my own code I generally use `serializers.ValidationError` unless I have a reason for wanting to handle the error on my own

Comment: Thank you very much @RishiG for explanation of ListSerializer which was exactly what I was looking for limiting instances which are going to be created.

About duplicates, your idea is idomatic for sure, but Im afraid unique_together specified in model is not being respected in ListSerializers somehow, it simply ignores it. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: That's why I suggested both options (specifying in the serializer or in the model).  Specifying in the model only checks when you try to save to the database.  Not sure if specifying your own `ListSerializer` has any effect on `unique_together`, though.